# Access parent property inside object literal

Tags: javascript

We have a JS framework that lets us set up "modules". Each module is added by calling the addModule method and passing a literal object that contains required properties about the module as well as optional methods. Example:

```
framework.addModule({

    id: "test-module",
    init: function () {
        //stuff to do when initializing like set up jQuery bindings

        $("div").click(function () {
            // need access to literal object so I can call:
            something.utility1();
        });

    },

    utility1: function () {
        something.utility2();
    },

    utility2: function () {
      // need access to literal object so I can call:
    }

});
```

I'm trying to figure out the easiest way to make the object itself available to any code, at any level, inside the object (in place of "something").

The best I've been able to do is to add a `this: this` property to the object and then inside of methods I can put `var module = this`, which works but requires that variable to be added to each module. I'd like to see if there's another way that wouldn't require adding a variable to each method. Thanks.

Thanks for the comments and, zzzzBov, thanks for your suggestions.

However, it looks like the below code will work best for my needs. The devs on my team are writing a lot of these modules and I need the solution to be clear to them. Having to call `$.proxy` could make it less clear. I was hoping to avoid having to put `var module = this` in each method, so it would be cleaner, but it seems that it's not possible without it.

```
framework.addModule({
    id: "test-module",
    init: function () {
        var module = this;    
        $("div").click(function () {            
            module.utility1();
        });
    },

    utility1: function () {
        var module = this;
        module.utility2();
    },

    utility2: function () {        
    }
});
```

If anyone has a cleaner solution, let me know.

Comment: you only get one "this", and your jQuery event handler has dibs on it. you only need to add var module=this to the top of methods that impose such a conflict. Normally, inside .init(), this.utility1() works as you you expect.

Comment: Can you modify `addModule` to also pass in a module name? Inside the module, it can reference itself by name.

Answer (score 0):

jQuery has a [`proxy`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.proxy/) method which will bind the function to a specific context. This would turn your event binding into:

```
$('div').click($.proxy(this, 'utility1'));
```

Alternatively, instead of using an object literal to instantiate the module object, you could instantiate an anonymous function:

```
framework.addModule(new function () {
    this.id = 'test-module';
    this.init = function () {
        $('div').click($.proxy(this, 'utility1'));
    };
    this.utility1 = function () {
        ...more code...
    };
    this.utility2 = this.utility1;
});
```